# How to create SSL certificate locally and move to windows 2003 server for IIS ASP.Net website?

Tags: windows-server-2003, asp.net, ssl-certificate

How can I create a SSL certificate, for testing purposes, on my local machine in a portable file such that I can move it to the Windows Server 2003 machine and install it there for a ASP.Net website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the article [Certificate Creation Tool (Makecert.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: Worked! Not sure about the gazillion attributes though. :)

Answer (score 0):

The information found on this website; http://www.xenocafe.com/tutorials/self_signed_cert_IIS/self_signed_cert_IIS-part1.php explained the steps in detail on how to create a self signed SSL certificate and how to import it to my server!